# Adding a toolbar to the bottom of my tableview

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar

I'm trying to add a toolbar at the bottom of my tableViewController. When I use this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
    let checkButton = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 46, self.view.frame.size.width, 48)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.setItems(checkButton, animated: true)
    toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
}
```

I get this as my result:

[image]

My questions are:
1) Why is the toolbar transparent?
2) Why does it not have a bar-button?

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I have now changed my code to the following:

```
func checkedPress(){

    println("saywhat")

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
    let checkButton = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Done, target: self, action: "checkedPress")]
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 46, self.view.frame.size.width, 48)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.setItems(checkButton, animated: true)
    toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
}
```

and it works, despite this bug:
[image]

as you can see, the toolbar follows the rest of the table when it is scrolled, which is not supposed to happen.

Again, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: 2. You have to set a title or a type for your UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: 1. I suppose the reason is : the tableview is in front of the toolbar, and the background color of that tableview is ClearColor (transparent).

Comment: `let checkButton = [UIBarButtonItem]()` sets `checkButton` to an empty array that holds items of type `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Try something like: `let checkButton = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Done, target: self, action: "donePressed")]`

Answer (score 0):

Since `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, you need to override the `scrollViewDidScrollMethod` method.

Inside your class, you can use this code.

`var toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let checkButton = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 46, self.view.frame.size.width, 48)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.setItems(checkButton, animated: true)
    toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var frame:CGRect = self.toolbar.frame
    frame.origin.y =  scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.tableView.frame.size.height - self.toolbar.frame.size.height
    self.toolbar.frame = frame

    self.view .bringSubviewToFront(self.toolbar)

}
```

`